# Is choosing an Elf subrace needed for making a Half-Elf?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races

When making a Half-Elf character, do I have to choose an elf subrace? If so, do I get any of the benefits of that subrace, or is it just for cosmetic purposes?

Answer (score 7):

### Without Variant rules, you don't have to choose a sub-race

The PHB only details one type of Half-elf and all the traits and features are listed there in page 28.

However, there are variant rules in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide found in page 116. As these are variant rules, ask your DM about it first; he/she may not allow it. The variant rules allow you to choose a sub-race for your elf-half, choosing from the Sun Elves (High Elves), Moon Elves (Wood Elves), Drow, or Aquatic.

Comment: I  would add that for the storytelling purpose it might be needed, and DM is free to require it even if it doesn't change anything for game mechanics. But then, one could be descendant of a long line of half elves with traces of blood leading to many subraces.