# I am confused about making a half-elf that is a drow

Tags: dnd-5e, races, racial-traits, half-elf, drow

I am thinking about making a new character and was wondering what would a half-elf with a drow history act like and if it would have something new. For example, would it have the drow magic trait? Or would it have light sensitivity? And if it is possible to make it, how would it be made?

Comment: Are you asking whether such a thing exists, or are you asking us to help you figure out how to make this? Because we handle the former, but not the latter.

Comment: Do you have access to the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide? (It was the first supplement published).  Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the tour and visit the help to see how a Q&A site is different from a discussion forum.  If you can add a little more detail to your question, it would be helpful.

Comment: I believe that they probably exist but I was wondering if it is possible to make and how to make it

Comment: I do not have it

Comment: related question is [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93672/22566)

Comment: Please let us know if that linked question answers yours.

Comment: Rubiksmoose It is similar but I want to know how to make it

Comment: @mustard we can't quote the entirety of the section as it is owned by Wizards of the Coast. You will have to purchase Swords Coast Adventurer's Guide or buy a digital copy of the race individually on dndbeyond.com

Comment: @mustard: Doesn't that answer tell you where to look to find the resources to make it?

Comment: If you go [this website](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/13) and scroll down to the Subraces section, you can get just the Half-Drow for only 1.99 USD as opposed to having to buy the whole book. D&D Beyond is officially endorsed and licensed by WoTC so it is the only way to get digital copies of the rules legally.

Comment: the link helped